# How would we make antimatter in industrial quantities?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, space, antimatter

### The Setting

Let's say, for the sake of argument, we have a dyson swarm. This very small torus of swarm mirrors collects over 20 exawatts of power in photons. Most of this power is lost, leaving only around 12 exawatts of power. Most of this is beamed around the solar system, so we will give ourselves about one exawatt to work with.

### The Question

With this budget of power, and a large orbit reserved for particle accelerators, assuming we can get at least a 75% efficiency in the process (converting electricity into the moving particles or photons, not the total efficiency of the machine), how would we make the antimatter itself? (what particles would we smash together and how? Linacs? Synchrotrons? Superfluidic photon-smashers?)

What kind of machines would they be? (And as a side note, how efficient would they be?)

The required product is anti-hydrogen snowballs and I expect no 'new' physics to be discovered, **but**, techniques that have been predicted but not proven are fine. I expect to get less than 0.001% efficiency or so, and most of that exawatt of power will be radiated away, but I have no experience in this field and want to get a rough outline.

### TO SUMMARISE: If you wanted to produce antimatter industrially with current physics, how would you do pull it off?

Comment: And also, any good ideas on how to recycle the waste energy? I'd be shocked if there's no way to reclaim some of that energy somehow. How much more efficient can we be if we do a matryoshka antimatter-heat engine system, where the waste heat of one powers the next.

Comment: And, depending on how we do it, would we want a big swarm of small particle accelerators, or do we want to build one massive machine?

Comment: I also see the issue of needing at least two different accelerator types, as you need to create antiprotons **and** positrons, and then guide them together with lasers and freeze them with **more lasers**.

Comment: There's two questions here: a worldbuilding question about the most efficient way to produce antimatter; and a physics question about why waste heat is waste heat.

Comment: You can use waste heat if you've got enough "shells" like you suggest. The problem is efficiency of converting that waste heat into something useful, which yields waste heat, ad infinitum. A 100 W incandescent bulb in your home is producing light *and* waste heat, in the form of thermal energy which heats your home, reducing the load on the gas heater. Now you want the bulb waste heat to power your TV? Thermal to electric efficiency is notoriously bad...

Comment: @BMF Of course it won't be at all efficient, but if we can reclaim just a little energy from the machines, say, for every five machines powered by the swarm, we can power a sixth for free, thats still a very, *very* good improvement. Personally I imagine using some sort of Seebeck effect-powered radiators that passively reclaim a little work from the moving heat, feeing it back into the machine.

Comment: This is perhaps a quibble, but 8 is not "most" of 20. If you had 20 eggs and I stole 8 of them, you would not say that I stole most of the eggs, you'd say I stole some but that you kept most.

Comment: @Tom, 12 exawatts is raw **beamed microwave power**, you'll loose some sending it across the solar system, directing it, turning it back into electricity, and sending it to whatever industrial processes you'll use it for. But for the sake of this argument, you *do* have all 12 exawatts at your disposal, because you're literally **on top** of the swarm. (and you'd probably loose another 20 ought percent of that 12 just in inefficiencies of shipping it around and turning it into electricity)

Comment: The radiation hazard from this industry will be ridiculous. But... you can try fusing the nuclear weak force with electromagnetism, and then use this electroweak force to attempt your alchemy. Actually, if you can do that, you can just conduct the radiation away.

Comment: @chiggsy can you explain more? I don't fully understand the four fundamental forces and all their intricacies, and how do you 'conduct' radiation?

Comment: @SamKitsune Once we thought that electricity and magnetism were different forces. Maxwell unified them, I believe. That's why we call it electromagnetism. We can do almost anything we want with this force, since it's range is infinite. Radiation decay, fusion and fission are mediated by the nuclear weak force. Range is subatomic. We aint great with this force. Turns out that it is our low energy living that makes these forces seem different. Standard Model says there is actually one force called the electroweak force. So in theory, since we can manipulate electromagnetism, we can do the same..

Comment: ... with fusion, fission, and radiation. There is lagniappe with this concept for us because the weak force is asymmetrical. This asymmetry is postulated to be a reason that there is so much more matter than antimatter, which is what you are making. Our existing mastery of EM phenomena is directly applicable to weak interactions, or rather there should be a state of being where the previous statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a (theoretical) thing called the [Schwinger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect), whereby creating an unreasonably intense electrical field can pull electron-positron pairs out of a vacuum (because of [vacuum polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization)).

Now, positrons aren't super interesting here, because whilst they're a great source of gamma rays they're hard to pack at high density (making them an awkward fuel) and there are a lot of useful things you can do with antibaryons (like pion rocketry and triggering fission and so on) that you can't do with antilepton.

Good news though. It *is* apparently possible to generate baryons via the same mechanism... there's a relevant physics.SE question which contains some paywalled links I haven't dug up, but you can take a look anyway: [Pair production of quarks](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266149/225554).

Whilst looking for a related paper, I ran across "[Estimates for the efficient production of antihydrogen by lasers of very high intensities](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02109654)" (by Heinrich Hora, 1973, I can't find any free *legitimate* sources online) which isn't an entirely consumer-friendly piece of work, but the key take-home message is that [pair-production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) of protons and antiprotons can theoretically be done by lighting up a blob of suitably dense plasma with an unreasonably powerful laser. From the conclusion of the paper,

> Considering a hydrogen plasma with densities exceeding $n_{cco}$ (10<sup>21</sup> cm<sup>-3</sup> or a little less due to relativistic effects) where neodymium glass laser pulses of intensities of 10<sup>19</sup> W cm<sup>-2</sup> corresponding to field strengths of ~ 10<sup>11</sup> V cm<sup>-1</sup> are incident, the pulse length being assumed sufficiently long (> 10<sup>-10</sup> s)... [snip] ...This would again increase $E^{act}$ within the next step of iteration with this last energy, we shall exceed the field strength at 10<sup>14</sup> V cm<sup>-1</sup> which will cause pair production of protons

Now, making a laser array that can deliver 10 exawatts over a tenth of a nanosecond or more, and then do it many many times over an extended period is left as an exercise for the reader, but if you could pull it off, you could electromagetically separate the spray of particles that came out and pocket the useful ones.

> And as a side note, how efficient would they be

Astonishingly bad. Not only will the lasers be fearsomely inefficient (though by the time you get to this point in the future, you'd expect a better grasp of making decent lasers) but an awful lot of the stuff that comes out of your matter-synthesizer will not be very useful to you... lots of unstable heavy particles, mesons and so on, probably an excess of electron-positron pairs. Even if your *mass* synthesis is relatively efficient (which it won't be, most likely) your *antihydrogen* synthesis will be somewhat less efficient.

The unstable particles will decay promptly and generate all sorts of inconvenient radiation. The more stable particle pairs might be pulled away and then allowed to annihilate in such a way that you could reclaim a portion of the energy that went into them, but that'll be an inefficient process too.

Ultimately, the efficiency can be driven by the needs of your plot. Clearly, *you* need enough to drive your ISV *Totally Not The Venture Star*, and so clearly your efficiency will be good enough to provide that much antihydrogen for you. Wave your hands. It'll be fine.

Comment: Ah, you got me with the last part! Still laughing! Nice. So the consensus is that I can make antimatter all three ways (photons, light and heavy particles). I think that (like BMF suggested) slamming heavy ions together (she said uranium) would (by the sound of it) be simpler and easier. And, the roadmap on how it works is funny! Step 1: Mine asteroid. Step 2: Collect its garbage. Step 3: Slam the waste together with a lot of violence. Step 4: **???** Step 5: Antimatter.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how an economy handles needing to produce all of those heavy radioactive nuclei for these machines. Suddenly, nuclear waste is about as valuable as copper.

Comment: And it's also noteworthy that they (big evil empire that built the *not so ISV Venture star*) would have decades of these machine running before they pump the fuel into their ships.

Comment: And no! I did **did not** rip off James Cameron. There's loads of differences! It's bigger and an-and... (Crap, thats it. It's just bigger. A lot bigger.) *frustrated Neko noises*

Answer (score 9):

### Laser Pincers

Particle accelerators take so much control that you can only make antimatter from matter 1 particle at a time.  [Laser Pincers](https://newatlas.com/physics/laser-pincers-antimatter-neutron-star/) work by firing lasers at each other through a [meta-material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) in such a way that the photon streams are focused into each other at the micrometer scale making about 100,000 times as many photon collisions happen for the energy of your lasers.  The result is a cloud of electrons and positrons.

You can then use magnetic fields to separate the resulting matter and antimatter plasma before it has a chance to annihilate.  So, not only does this theoretically give your 6 orders of magnitude more efficiency than previous methods, but it's also able to be done as a continuous process assuming you can find a way to manage the heat.

I suspect that the best option is actually to go small instead of big.  You just need photons to hit each other; so, if the metamaterial were a small fiber and the lasers shooting into it also relatively small, then heat could be dissipated more quickly.  So a single antimatter factory could be a cellular configuration of millions of little laser pincers running around the clock feeding into large antimatter containment chambers.

This also assumes only modern levels of meta-material design.  A more advanced civilization could perhaps squeeze many more orders of magnitude of efficiency with better meta-materials. With good enough of a metamaterial you could in theory trap all of your photons in continuous loops until a considerable fraction are converted into matter/antimatter pairs.  This could result in actual economically viable antimatter mass production within just 1 or 2 orders of magnitude of ideal conversion which is actually much better than your hoped for 0.001%.

### Why this is better than single laser Schwinger effect generation?

The Schwinger effect can not produce anti-hydrogen snowballs by any known mechanism.  It can produce positron/electron pairs but does not actually have any established theory for making proton/anti-proton pairs in a single beam system.  However, using colliding neutron and proton beams fueled by decaying radioactive material funneled through a similar pincer system, you could in theory generate the needed antiprotons to create your snowballs.  So, one pincer system would make the positrons, another would make the antiprotons, and then a series of magnetic fields could be used to combine the antiparticle plasmas into atomic antimatter which can then be cooled and condensed down into an anti-matter snowball.

But the most important feature of pincer beams is efficiency.  Industrialization is all about efficiency, and relying on the Schwinger effect is so many orders of magnitude less efficient and than laser pincers, that no advanced civilization would chose it as a means to produce antimatter at a large scale, even if you don't assume particle recycling as an option.  But since we are talking about a civilization that can make a Dyson Sphere, I think a little particle recycling is not an unreasonable technological stretch when we are so close to being able to do that sort of thing with modern technology already.

### Why it might be better to make positron plasma instead of anti-hydrogen snowballs?

For starters, it is much safer to contain positron plasma than an anti-hydrogen snowball.  Just because an anti-hydrogen snowball is solid does not mean it will not violently react with normal matter meaning it still needs to be contained with a magnetic field.  Positrons are extremely reactive to magnetic fields because they are pure charged particles.  Once you start binding positrons to antiprotons, you start making an electromagnetically neutral material.  Technically you can leave it a bit ionized, and still contain it but it will be more sensitive to being knocked out of its magnetic containment than a plasma.

Secondly, going back to the economics aspect of industrialization, anti-protons are harder to make than positrons.  Laser pincers can simply be powered by your nearly inexhaustible supply of sunlight, but proton/neutron pincers means you need a very large supply of decaying heavy elements. This is certainly still doable since your civilization is clearly able gather massive amounts of materials into one place to be able to make a Dyson Sphere anyway, but it's not nearly as clean and controllable of a process.

Controlling the flow of electrons compared to solid matter is also much easier; so, when it comes to getting energy out of a positron cloud, all you have to do is zap it with a well regulated flow of electricity, and you will get exactly as much heat out of the system as you need. Getting a controllable flow of power out of interactions between solids is much more difficult to do with any precision. If you accidently spray the snowball with just a bit too much matter, you could kick it through its containment which would be very bad for anyone within a few miles.

Comment: Good answer, and useful too, but it **has** to be snowballs, as it is being used in diamagnetic anti-hydrogen powered tractor ships that can reach 0.7C. Think the ISV Venture Star from Avatar.

Comment: One way to make it more efficient is to figure out if it were possible to re-culminate the beam and continue to reuses the un-collided photons. I assume you'd want to have massive, individual space station complexes that either make both and export the snowballs, or specialize in one or the other... then have dedicated recombination facilities to turn the clouds of half-fuel into full snowballs.

Comment: Thank... y'all?

Comment: Thank y'all for the answer...

Comment: That just sounds weird.

Comment: @SamKitsune In theory, a similar setup should work by colliding  Proton and Neutron beams... but high precision Proton and Neutron beams are not nearly as simple to make as lasers.

Comment: @SamKitsune I've updated my answer to address anti-hydrogen snowball creation, and why I did not go with the Schwinger effect as the accepted answer did.

Comment: I am not an expert, but from what I understood of antimatter catalyzed systems (starships) is that anti-hydrogen throws off charged pions for thrust, which can be directed more easily than collecting power from gama rays to heat the reaction mass. Secondly, density. This stuff (anti-hydrogen) isn't your run-of-the-mill fuel that you find at any old depot, it only serves for fueling these ships. *(continued)*

Comment: The problem with the ISVs is that they have to be as light as physically possible, because they are horribly strangled by the tyranny of the rocket equation, so they have to be as light and power-dense as possible. Not only are the pions easier to turn into thrust, but there is a limit to the trap size for positronium. after which, you'd need to make multiple of them, as the repulsion force grows exponentially. (I need to double-check, but I believe I this is the same reason neutrons are needed to keep atoms stable, because of the nuclear force / charge balance.)

Comment: But for commercial use, positronium would work better for catalyzed fusion engines, which I will definitely keep in mind, as a few of the larger ships that appear **must** use something better than a standard fusion torch drive, or risk being rather dinky.

Comment: But industrialization isn't that big of a concern, because all the infrastructure is basically one-use. After the 800 or so tonnes of fuel are loaded into the ships, there isn't a need for that much antimatter for the next forty years of cruising those ships will make. Sidenote, is there a way to direct gamma rays before they are emitted, using positronium as a lasing medium? Starts imagining giant antimatter-powered laser arrays*

Comment: I thought I read something about creating orbitals of electron-positron 'atoms' in their ground quantum state, so that they orbited each other and would act as one massive atomic structure, thus firing their gamma rays on a single axis.

Comment: @SamKitsune Remember that antimatter is not fuel, matter + antimatter is fuel. 
 Antimatter as reaction mass is very dangerous and expensive.  You can slam hydrogen into positronium giving your a stream of spare protons just as easily as you can slam electrons into antihydrogen to get stream of spare anti-protons... but the protons won't blow you your whole ship up quite so easily if some just so happen to graze the body of your thruster.  That said, there may be an advantage to antimatter that can be stored as a solid from a container weight perspective; so that part I get.

Comment: As for cost: if your civilization has the option of spending almost 600 years fueling a ship with the Schwinger effect, or a couple of hours using laser pincers, there is no reason to think they would chose the Schwinger effect. If you want it to take a long time to make the ship for plot reasons, consider the fact that the antimatter facility and ship itself would takes decades of RnD and construction to create.

Comment: Another option to consider when reaching 0.7C is that you don't need to do your acceleration with antimatter at all.  You could accelerate your ship with solar sails using beams powered by your Dyson Sphere, then only use the anti-matter to slow down.  That will make your Tyranny of Rockets problem way less tyrannical since your acceleration phase can be done with non-carried energy.

Comment: Yes, I already accounted for doing that. Mostly. But if you wanted to know exactly how I planned on it, you can take a look at my post about blowing up an antimatter powered spaceship, which details all the specifications for the ship I have planned, although my understanding of how the ship would have worked was woefully flawed back then.. so take what I said then with a grain of salt. I'm still learning ^-^ ...and kind of proud of myself, only barely entering highschool.

Answer (score 7):

### The theoretical limit

The theoretical maximum efficiency of turning electricity into antimatter is 50% due to the [Law of Baryon Number Conservation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number#Conservation), which mandates that energy be turned into equal amounts of matter and antimatter. So, in the limit of technological advancement, for every 100 MW of production energy, 50 MW of matter-antimatter reaction energy may be produced. (Use $E=mc^2$ to determine the *mass* instead.)

### Robert L. Forward's numbers

Current particle accelerators aren't designed to make antimatter. Their input energy to antimatter efficiency is 0.000002%, at 100 trillion USD a gram. Robert L. Forward wrote a book with Joel Davis titled *Mirror Matter: Pioneering Antimatter Physics (Wiley, 1988)*. In it he discussed heavy ion beam colliders, with anticipated improvements in superconducting magnets, to produce large quantities on the cheap. Beams of uranium atoms could collide to produce $10^{18}$ antiprotons per second (and a *lot* of nuclear fragments), at an efficiency of 0.01%. For every 100 MW of beam power, 100 W of antimatter-stored energy is produced (and the remaining 999,900 W are waste heat).

The antimatter factory could draw energy from a space-based solar array. Here's Forward's words on that from *Indistinguishable from Magic (Baen, 1995)*:

> Where will we get the energy to run these magic matter factories? Some of the prototype factories will be built on Earth, but for large scale production we certainly don’t want to power these machines by burning fossil fuels on Earth. There is plenty of energy in space. At the distance of the Earth from the Sun, the Sun delivers over a kilowatt of energy for each square meter of collector, or a gigawatt (1,000,000,000 watts) per square kilometer. A collector array of one hundred kilometers on a side would provide a power input of ten terawatts (10,000,000,000,000), enough to run a number of antimatter factories at full power, producing a gram of antimatter a day.

---

You say you want to use the waste heat to make more antimatter, but there's always more sunlight to take advantage of. The machinery to use waste heat will grow exponentially large due to the compounding losses (everything has waste heat, nothing's 100% efficient). You're much better off making more solar arrays.

Comment: Well... for one, good answer, and according to what I've gathered here, I'd ideally build a large ring of antimatter production stations in an even higher orbit than the ring of collectors, which themselves sit over the torus of mirrors. (detailed in that 'destroying a dyson swarm' post) You'd then have half the station dedicated (actually probably less) to laser colliders, producing positronium.

Comment: And the other half (probably more) to heavy ion colliders, producing... anti-protonium? Don't think thats a proper term but it is now! Then, just throw them together... slowly... into anti-hydrogen, and freeze it with lasers. And Viola! Hundreds of tonnes of fuel for going on a four-decade-long star-conquering escapade.

Comment: Well hey! I guess I overestimated how hard it would be to do this, looking back at my atrociously underpowered tractor ships, it wouldn't be that hard (from a believability perspective) for them to carry hundreds of tonnes of antimatter, if need be. I will probably do a post to double-check my math, but I haven't sat down and carefully read Hro and calculated the specifics, but it looks like the fuel side won't be that hard to justify.

Comment: @SamKitsune Yeah, antiprotons are ionized antihydrogen, and you can freeze them into solid blocks if you wish. Note that with heavy ion beams some of your operation will involve mining heavy elements like uranium, either from Earth or across the solar system. If you can get the cost of antimatter to below $10M USD per milligram, antimatter propulsion becomes cheaper than fission propulsion (depending on thrust efficiency), so using uranium isn't a loss. With antimatter thermal using heated hydrogen, 10 milligrams yields about the same thrust as 120 tonnes of conventional rocket fuel.

Comment: @SamKitsune you talk about building a Dyson swarm in your earlier posts. A 100km^2 solar array really isn't a big deal to build, and one gram a day is nothing to sneeze at. 1000 of those and you're making a kilogram a day, for only a fraction of your total swarm's output. Times ten years? A few tonnes.

Comment: If you'd also use all this antimatter for domestic purposes, I assume you'd be best off using some kind of 'dirty' antimatter-catalyzed fusion engines, dirty being that they spew off lots of deadly radiation. I guess it would be interesting to se how industries would grow out to organically fill this new, massive demand for heavy nuclei. Does it have to be uranium though? I guess its a fantastic way to use up all but the most high-grade and fissile (or useful) radioactive elements that you'd get as 'waste' from asteroid mining.

Comment: @SamKitsune I'm not sure, I don't have the book at hand. I imagine you could get away with a variety of heavy elements. Uranium and plutonium are probably the best naturally occurring options though.

Comment: The whole waste heat thing, wouldnt it be prudent to try and bounce it to the middle? You cant say “there’s always more energy from the sun”, at least not when you start planning long term. Also they found some niche property of Graphene which turns heat vibrations into energy, so maybe layers and layers of those could turn that heat into energy with the only losses being the vibrations and black body radiation they pass on to other materials.

Comment: @Demigan Maybe. You need a thermal gradient to do work. If you bury the first layer by more "above" it, you subject the first to a thermal bath the temperature of its own waste heat and it's unable to do anything. You then need to run a cooling system to artificially create that thermal gradient (rather than having the naturally cold void at your back being there for you). Moving heat around creates more waste heat, a little more cooling is required, etc., until your operation is mostly thermal management system by mass.

Comment: @BMF you seem to have looked up Thermoelectrics which need a temperature difference. The Graphene thing seems more a piezoelectric like effect which turns the direct hear vibrations into electricity. Ofcourse the questions about its bulk production, thermal conductivity etc are still up in the air so it might not be feasible for large projects like this.

Comment: @Demigan Can piezoelectrics draw energy from a heat bath/Brownian motion? Unless there's a temperature gradient, useful work can't be done or else you've made a free-energy machine.

Comment: Also, in space the problem will be getting rid of all this waste heat. This heat is at the bottom of the entropy pyramid. It's the opposite of lasers in fact. Useless. But you need to get rid of it, and your waste heat as well. I think cooling is going to be your biggest worry, space is a perfect insulator. You got lasers and antimatter, and you, and your machinery, you dont want to recycle that heat you want to dump it!

Comment: @bmf as mentioned, the point of that Graphene variation was that it could extract energy from heat vibrations directly, no heat variation required. Chiggsy’s problem of low heat dissipation in space is a great advantage there as you can capture that heat and convert it for longer. There’s even entire planet sized brains based on heat slowly moving up the layers, extracting energy from it until it leaves proposed and that is without this Graphene variant.

Comment: @Demigan reading [articles like this one](https://physicsworld.com/a/rippling-graphene-harvests-thermal-energy/), and watching a couple animated videos, they dance around the subject of where the energy produced by the circuit originates.  They claim a 10x10 square micron generator can produce 10 microwatts of power. If my math is correct, a square meter of these things would produce 100 kW of power, 100x solar insolation on Earth. They also claim no waste heat is made. (Why use solar panels instead of these things?) In short, I distrust anything that claims to be a "free energy" source.

Answer (score 0):

## Major Frame Challenge

Assuming a merely 1000 tons for your space ship, at 0.7c its kinetic energy is around 36000 ExaJoules. We can double that if you want to brake as well, but a factor of two will not be of concern here.

Assuming a 100% conversion rate<sup>1</sup> (haha, massive overestimation), you'd need around 200 tons of anti matter.

As mentioned in another answer, and quoting from [projectrho.com](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/antimatterfuel.php#antifactory) making antimatter (specifically anti protons) is totally inefficient.

> [...] it will take 1.50327759×10-6 Joules to make 1 antiproton, or 8.988×1017 Joules (899 exaJoules) to make one kilogram of antiprotons.

Note, we need a factor of at least 200,000, so the input energy would be around 18000 yotaJoules. Thanks to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=18000+yotajoules) we know that this is around 47 times the energy output of the entire sun in 1 second (so with your current 12 exaWatts setup, it'd take around 47.5 years).

And now we're not even talking about anything else. Anti matter on this scale is the most volatile object you can think of. If the anti matter storage tank fails, it will fail apocalyptically and the entire ship is gone within a fraction of a second. Would you build a ship like this? No.

Honestly, I wouldn't go into the details here, just state that it's possible, not how it's possible. That's way better than winging it with all these contradictions and impossibilities. Suspension of disbelief only works, if there's nothing contradicting about it. The more details you specify, there more contradictions can be found. At this point, it's more plausible that the ship flies with *magic*.

<sup>1</sup> just remember, if you halve the conversion rate, you need to double the other numbers (and so on).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141895/discussion-on-answer-by-infinitezero-how-would-we-make-antimatter-in-industrial).

Comment: I would need to figure out if it is even possible to collimate a laser over 20 ought lightyears. At that point, it's better to combo the superconducting ring-thingy and small antimatter engines when diminishing returns on the ring make it pointless to keep using. And at that point things are easy, compared to how I originally thought they'd work. And besides, the ship only has to be used once, and each one has a sister ship, so catastrophic failure is fine, as long as at least one survives transit (interstellar meteors, GRBs and other space cataclysms)

Comment: The OP is only budgeting 1 exawatt for antimatter production, so actually 570  years.